# Get specific word with Regex in HTML irregular pattern

Tags: regex, web-scraping

I'm trying to get an article ID from a webpage, Im currently using xpath. But I don't know anything about regex, I think REGEX is the solution.

This is an example of the original code:

```
<div id="description" class="panel" style="display: block; overflow: hidden;"><h2 class="open">Descripción</h2><div class="productDescription">NEUROBION INYECTABLE X 3 AMPOLLAS<br><br>Modo de Uso: Vía Intramuscular<br>Componente Activo:Vitamina B1 (Tiamina) 100 Mg, Vitamina B6 (Piridoxina) 100 Mg Y Vitamina B12 (Cianocobalamina) 1 Mg. Solucion Inyectable Con Tecnología Doble Camara. <br>INVIMA 2015M-13939-R2<br><img class="" data-src="/arquivos/RX.png?v=636054173313030000" src="/arquivos/RX.png?v=636054173313030000"></div></div>
```

These are 2 examples that I got from screaming frog using xpath:

```
<div class="productDescription">NEUROBION 100MG/150MG CAJA X 30 TABLETAS<br><br>Modo de Uso: Vía Oral<br>Componente Activo: Vitamina B1 (Tiamina) Y Vitamina B6 (Piridoxina)<br>INVIMA 2019M-0009578-R1</div>

<div class="productDescription">NEUROBION INYECTABLE X 3 AMPOLLAS<br><br>Modo de Uso: Vía Intramuscular<br>Componente Activo:Vitamina B1 (Tiamina) 100 Mg, Vitamina B6 (Piridoxina) 100 Mg Y Vitamina B12 (Cianocobalamina) 1 Mg. Solucion Inyectable Con Tecnología Doble Camara. <br>INVIMA 2015M-13939-R2<br><img class="" data-src="/arquivos/RX.png?v=636054173313030000" src="/arquivos/RX.png?v=636054173313030000"></div>
```

But I just want to get this:

```
INVIMA 2015M-13939-R2
INVIMA 2019M-0009578-R1
```

This is what I already have done with xpath

```
//div[@id="description"]//div
```

Can somebody help me with the Regex Formula?

I also tried with this:

```
["'](INVIMA .*?)["']
```

Comment: You might need to look at [this well-known answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Maybe use a parser is a better idea but if you can't use it or don't want this pattern based on your example works: `(?<=<br>)[\w -]+(?=<\/?(?:div|br)>)` See Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8QxasW/1

Comment: `INVIMA` is always in your texts?

Comment: If `INVIMA` is always in your texts this pattern is better `(?<=INVIMA )[^<]+` See Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8QxasW/2

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
INVIMA [A-Z0-9-]+
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/iqPaZG/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  INVIMA                   'INVIMA '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z0-9-]+               any character of: 'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9',
                           '-' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
```